# "Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable" -Every thing looks right

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to write simple map reduce program to find largest prime number using new API (0.20.2). This is how my Map and reduce class look like…

```java
public class PrimeNumberMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

public void map (LongWritable key, Text Kvalue,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    Integer value = new Integer(Kvalue.toString());
    if(isNumberPrime(value))
    {
            context.write(new IntWritable(value), new IntWritable(new Integer(key.toString())));
    }
}

boolean isNumberPrime(Integer number)
{
    if (number == 1) return false;
     if (number == 2) return true;

     for (int counter =2; counter<(number/2);counter++)
     {
         if(number%counter ==0 )
             return false;
     }
            return true;

}
}
public class PrimeNumberReduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable>  {

public void reduce ( IntWritable primeNo, Iterable<IntWritable> Values,Context context) throws IOException ,InterruptedException
{
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (IntWritable value : Values)
    {
        maxValue=  Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
    }
    //output.collect(primeNo, new IntWritable(maxValue));
    context.write(primeNo, new IntWritable(maxValue));  }

}  

 public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{

    if (args.length ==0)
    {
        System.err.println(" Usage:\n\tPrimenumber <input Directory> <output Directory>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(Main.class);

    job.setJobName("Prime");
    // Creating job configuration object

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path (args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    String star ="*********************************************";
    System.out.println(star+"\n Prime number computer \n"+star);
    System.out.println(" Application started ... keeping fingers crossed :/ ");
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);

}

}
```

I am still getting error regarding mismatch of key for map

> java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1034)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:595)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:668)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:334)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1109)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
>   2012-06-13 14:27:21,116 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task

Can some one please suggest what is wrong. I have tried all hooks and crooks.

Answer (score 8):

You've not configured the Mapper or reducer classes in your main block, so the default Mapper is being used - which is known as the identity mapper - each pair it receives as input is output (hence the LongWritable as the output key):

```
job.setMapperClass(PrimeNumberMap.class);
job.setReducerClass(PrimeNumberReduce.class);
```

Comment: Thanks alot... It was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: How to to configure them?

Answer (score 0):

1. The mapper should be defined as below,

   ```
   public class PrimeNumberMap extends Mapper<**IntWritable**, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   public class PrimeNumberMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
   ```
2. As it is mentioned in the comment before you should have the mapper and reducer defined.

   ```
   job.setMapperClass(PrimeNumberMap.class);
   job.setReducerClass(PrimeNumberReduce.class);
   ```

Please refer to Hadoop Definitive guide 3rd edition, Chapter 2, Page 24

Answer (score 0):

I am a fresh hand in hadoop mapreduce program.

When mapping, I use `IntWritable` but I reduce the values in `IntWritable` format and convert the result to double before using `DoubleWritable` in context write.

It fails when running.

My method to handle the covert int in map to double in reduce is:

```
Mapper(LongWritable,Text,Text,DoubleWritable)
Reducer(Text,DoubleWritable,Text,DoubleWritable)
job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.Class)
```